# every time i node . the bot shows n error

Tags: node.js

i reinstalled node.js and i reinstalled better-sqlite3 and still this problem

````
  return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
                 ^

Error: The module '\\?\D:\discordbots\dc.RSG.Bot.2.0\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\better_sqlite3.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 67. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 64. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:718:18)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\discordbots\dc.RSG.Bot.2.0\node_modules\better-sqlite3\lib\database.js:5:21)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)```
````

Comment: fixed by deleting the node_modules and package.json

Comment: If you have fixed you problem and think the solution might be interesting for other people, please post your solution as an answer to the question and mark this answer as accepted. If you think the solution is not interesting, please delete your question.